# Cannot add or change onSubmit() attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form and two buttons. I want to change the `onsubmit attribute` of the form using these buttons using `jQuery`.

I tried the

```
$("#form").attr("onsubmit","newValue")
```

but this doesn't change the onsubmit attribute nor add the attribute to the form.

Please help.

Comment: When you say "onsubmit", are you talking about the JavaScript event handler for your form?

Answer (score 7):

Just use $("#form").submit();

Like this:

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
//Prevent form submit: e.preventDefault()
//Do whatever
});
```