# Error with a href click

Tags: javascript

I have a problem to share with you guys..In my page I have different tabs that was created by some method, before moving onto another tab i need to do some validations, but the problem is when i click next tab the page is submitted before going to my validation check even though they check the validation script is executed but because of the page is submitted first it's moving to the next tab.How can i prevent moving to next tab if validation is false.

Code for a href click:

```
<a onclick="adc.FormHandler.goto('user_edit', 0); return false;" 
   href="#">
  <i data="1" class="icon-tab-num"></i> 
  General Info
</a>
```

code for actual click function

```
if (null !== document.forms[formName]) {
    document.forms[formName].elements['__goto'].value = gotoIndex;
    document.forms[formName].submit();
    return false;
}
```

I can't modify these scripts because this is a general script and created by some other team memeber.I am using jquery for validation.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Is the current page supposed to be submitted when moving to the next tab? Is that how you "move" between the tabs?

Comment: Actually no need to submit but..it's dynamically created and i have to use this

Comment: The problem is that you submit the form on clicking :-/, there is no way that without changing the code or the markup to modify this behavior

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am understanding your problem incorrectly, it looks like you are submitting the form regardless of whether or not you return false. And so it will never actually return a false.

You should do something like

```
if (null !== document.forms[formName]) {
    document.forms[formName].elements['__goto'].value = gotoIndex;
    return false;
}
else{
    document.forms[formName].submit();
}
```

Comment: This code is created by somebody else and i can't modify this code...do we have some other method to handle this like cancel the submition something like that

Comment: Some javascript like this might work? Never tried it. 

if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
window.document.execCommand('Stop');
}
else
{
window.stop();
}

Source: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=85775

Comment: Can you edit the form tag in the HTML? You could also tie into the onsubmit and stop it by returning false. 

IE: <form onsubmit="stopFunction()">

Comment: can tell me a way to modify for add a method form onsubmit in jquery by runtime

Comment: $("#form").submit(function(e){
//Prevent form submit: e.preventDefault()
//Do whatever
});

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294085/cannot-add-or-change-onsubmit-attribute-using-jquery